# How do I avoid BindingExpression path errors on bound properties that aren't always present?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following hierarchical data template defined:

`<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubEntries}">`

`SubEntries` can be objects of various types. The issue is, not every type actually defines `SubEntries`. (These are objects for a tree, and certain entries don't have subentries).

For example, here is an object that can be contained within `SubEntries` that has its own `SubEntries`:

```
public class ScriptLevelLog : LogContainer
{
        public List<LogContainer> SubEntries { get; set; }

        public ScriptLevelLog()
        {
            SubEntries = new List<LogContainer>();
        }

        [JsonConstructor]
        public ScriptLevelLog(LogType logType, string time, string action, string target, string description, int lineNumber) : base(logType, time, action, target, description, lineNumber)
        {
            SubEntries = new List<LogContainer>();
        }
}
```

And here is one that does not:

```
public class DebugLevelLog : LogContainer
{
        public DebugLevelLog()
        {

        }

        [JsonConstructor]
        public DebugLevelLog(LogType logType, string time, string action, string target, string description, int lineNumber) : base(logType, time, action, target, description, lineNumber)
        {

        }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid data binding errors in this situation, or do I need to rethink my bound objects?

Comment: set DataType for HierarchicalDataTemplate (for each type). or ignore the errors

Comment: I figured it would be something simple like this. Thanks!